# Why use temporal logic for interpolation-based model checking?

Tags: logic, temporal, model-checking

I am new in model checking field. I want to know why it's preferred to use linear-time temporal logic properties in interpolation and bounded model checking. Why can't we directly use propositional logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can also restrict yourself to propositional logic, but then you cannot express interesting properties of your model.

**Propositional logic** is less expressive than temporal logic. In propositional logic you can only describe one situation/state/world, and model checking is very easy: Given the current state (i.e. the set of true propositions) you only need to evaluate a propositional formula.

In contrast, **temporal logics** like [LTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic) can talk about the future and the past, with operators like Gϕ saying "ϕ will always be true in the future". A model for temporal logic then is not just the current state, but also a description (transition relation) of what was the case before and how it will develop.